# SQLAlchemy connects to SQLServer using Windows Authenticaton with pymssql driver

Tags: python, sql-server, sqlalchemy, pymssql

I can use pymssql to connect to SQLServer using **Windows Authentication**:

```
conn = pymssql.connect(host='..', database='..', trusted=True)
```

But how could I use **SQLAlchemy** to connect to SQLServer using Windows Authenticaton with pymssql driver?

The example given by SQLAlchemy is:

```
mssql+pymssql://<username>:<password>@<freetds_name>
```

Since I use Windows Authentication, I cannot manually set the username and password.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do not have `pymssql` to check, but try the version below:

```
mssql+pymssql://<freetds_name>?trusted=True
```