# Windows Authentication With SQLAlchemy and pymssql

Tags: python, sql-server, sql-server-2012, sqlalchemy, pymssql

I want to create trusted connections to a SQL Server database, using pymssql. Given that that code is going to be shared though, I don't want users entering their usernames, or passwords. I've found documentation that has conflicting information about how to achieve this.

What I want to be able to do is something like

```
engine = create_engine('mssql+pymssql://<Server>/<Database>?trusted=True')
```

Some things have said use  [trusted_connection=yes](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/sqlalchemy/PE8Np2QCFEs), others say use [trusted=True](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8284181/sqlalchemy-connects-to-sqlserver-using-windows-authenticaton-with-pymssql-driver). Neither of these options is working for me. Each time I try to use the engine I get an error saying that `trusted` or `trusted_connection` is an unexpected keyword argument.

I'm using SQLAlchemy version 1.0.9, and pymssql version 2.1.1.

Comment: Answered here with pyodbc https://stackoverflow.com/a/7399585/3406189

Answer (score 6):

I just tested this on a Windows machine with

- Python 2.7.11, SQLAlchemy 1.0.11, and pymssql 2.1.1, and
- Python 3.5.1, SQLAlchemy 1.0.14, and pymssql 2.1.2 (with FreeTDS 0.95.83 DLLs)

and it worked fine for me:

```python
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
conn_str = r'mssql+pymssql://(local)\SQLEXPRESS/myDb'
engine = create_engine(conn_str)
connection = engine.connect()
result = connection.execute("SELECT SYSTEM_USER AS me")
row = result.fetchone()
print(row['me'])
```

And, even when the SQL Browser service was stopped on that machine, this connection string worked

```python
conn_str = r'mssql+pymssql://localhost:52865/myDb'
```

So, at least on Windows machines, simply omitting the username and password will allow connections to the SQL Server via Windows authentication.

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone else stumbles into this one:
*It seems like its no longer possible to use "Trusted", or windows auth, with pymssql.*

I just attempted this and found a bunch of threads with dismayed users from the last couple of years. 
For example: 
[pymssql windows authentication](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29349607/pymssql-windows-authentication).

Edit: 
Resolved after enabling TCP/IP for the local SQL Server Express

Comment: Maybe things have changed since those comments were written, but when I tested it just now it worked for me. See my answer for details.

Comment: I've tried following your approach but I cant get it to work. I'm not using SQLAlchemy though. ex: 
conn = pymssql.connect(server='localhost', database='TestDB' )

Comment: I just tested `cnxn = pymssql.connect(server='localhost', port='52865', database='myDb')` and it worked for me with Python 3.5.1 and pymssql 2.1.2.

Comment: Okay! Now it I got it working with Python 2.7. I was using Sql Server Express and needed to enable TCP/IP.